# Unable to run awk command using python "commands" module. Issue with quotes

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, ssh

I want to update second column of second line in a file (file_from) and save the results in 'file_to' via ssh on different machine & user. I'm using PyQt module for the GUI and in that I used 'commands' module for running shell script.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
command =  "ssh abc@xyz \"awk 'FNR==2{$2=1};1' file_from > file_to\""
commands.getoutput(command)
```

but all it does is clear (empty) my file `file_to`

Comment: what does the bash history of that user say it ran? That might help you see what's happening.

Comment: `>` overwrites a file while `>>` appends to it.

Comment: @KeefBaker I did ran 'history' command in abc@xyz but it doesn't show any history via tool/GUI.

Comment: @NullDev We want to overwrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to run a command with complex quoting via ssh is always tricky, because it goes through an additional level of token expansion on the remote host.  That is, if you run:

```
ssh anotherhost awk '{print "hello", $1}' myfile
```

That gets tokenized on the remote host as:

```
argv[0] = awk
argv[1] = {print
argv[2] = hello,
argv[3] = }
argv[4] = myfile
```

Which is almost never what you want.  From the command line, you would need to execute something like:

```
ssh anotherhost "awk 'FNR==2 {\$2=1};1' file_from > file_to"
```

This ensures proper tokenization on the remote end, and avoids the variable expansion that would otherwise happen.  Now you just need to wrap that with `commands.getoutput`:

```
commands.getoutput('''ssh anotherhost "awk 'FNR==2 {\$2=1};1' file_from > file_to"''')
```

Here we're using python's triple quote to avoid having to add any additional escaping.

For anything more complicated, you are better off copying a script file to the remote host, or just opening a shell and writing your script to stdin.